# filter results by category on my site is slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, filtering, categories

My site has filters for categories, as are many, the website is very slow.

Each filter returns a result table by the main database.

Does anyone know any technique to be faster?

Each filter is a query in the main table that contains 6,000 records

Several websites use this feature results by category, but I would like to know how to do this more optimally.

SOLUTION:

I use only a query returning all registers, and with php functions I work the array for return the value total the registers for each filter.

SIMPLIFIED PSEUDOCODE:

```
$cont = array();

$res = mysql_query("SELECT field FROM info");

while($x = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    if ($x['field'] == "val1")
        $cont['val1'] ++;

    if ($x['field'] == "val2")
        $cont['val2'] ++;
}

echo "Filter val1: ".$cont['val1'];
echo "Filter val2: ".$cont['val2'];
```

Comment: show me your SQL Query, please

Comment: simple queries, filters use indexes and not use order by. Each website has a filter in the query like this below.

example:

Baú (100 results) use the query: SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtd FROM frete WHERE idtype = 1;
Caçamba (1.234 results) use the query: SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtd FROM frete WHERE idtype = 2;
Grade Baixa (432 results) use the query: SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtd FROM frete WHERE idtype = 3;

- Filters are several categories per page, about 35.
- I have 'index' on the field 'idtype'
- The website reaches 500 users online

Server settings:
Memory: 8GB
CPU: 4x 1500 Mhz
Link: 4MB

Comment: resultados spanish for results? run an EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtd FROM frete WHERE idtype = 1 and EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtd FROM frete WHERE idtype = 2  an post the outputs here

Comment: Results in Portuguese, Brazil.

Query:
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtd FROM frete WHERE codtype = 14;

Results:
SELECT_TYPE: SIMPLE; 
TABLE: frete; 
TYPE: ref; 
POSSIBLE_KEYS: especie; 
KEY: especie; 
KEY_LEN: 4; 
REF: const; 
ROWS 2.344;

Comment: code or it didn't happen